# how to create git repositiory for already existing project

Tags: git

I have some projects on my local machine. I would like to add these projects to my github repository. For that, first i created a new repository then on my local machine i changed to that dir and use the below commands

```
git inint
git add *
git commit -m "message"
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/project.git
git push origin
```

but it says

```
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: what does `git branch` return ?

Answer (score 3):

`Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'`

is important

use its advice

`git push origin master`

Answer (score 0):

if you don't specify the refs to push, git will consult the config as to what to do. The default behavior (in git <2.0) is matching (from the git man-page):

```
matching - push all branches having the same name in both ends. This is for those who prepare all the branches into a publishable shape and then push them out with a
           single command. It is not appropriate for pushing into a repository shared by multiple users, since locally stalled branches will attempt a non-fast forward push if
           other users updated the branch.
```

If you are using the default config, it seems that you don't have a branch in origin called `master` (the default branch name).

You should use the full syntax when pushing your first commit, specifying the remote, local ref and remote ref. I'd recommend using it always, since it will avoid you pushing things you didn't intend to:

```
git push <remote> <local_ref>:<remote_ref>
git push origin master:master
```

This way you can create new remote branches, or push branches which differ in name. For example:

```
git push origin master:master_backup
git push origin dev:master
```